# How to fix install error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot"?

Tags: 16.04, python3, pip, matplotlib

I am trying to install `pyplot` as follows:

```
x@y:~$ sudo -H pip3 install pyplot
Collecting pyplot
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyplot
```

What am I doing wrong? 
What conditions doesn't my platform meet?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit).
To provide some further context here are some of my package versions:

```
x@y:~$ pip3 show pip
Name: pip
Version: 9.0.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: python-virtualenv@groups.google.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/sebastian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 

x@y:~$ pip3 show matplotlib
Name: matplotlib
Version: 2.1.2
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: http://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: six, pyparsing, numpy, python-dateutil, pytz, cycler
```

Comment: Isn't pyplot included in matplotlib ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyplot` is part of a `matplotlib`.
In order to install `pyplot` you should install `matplotlib`

[`matplotlib` install instructions](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#linux)

> - Using package manager:
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
>   ```
> - Install `Anaconda` or `Canopy` which are both excellent choices that “just work” out of the box.

Comment: You are right. To succesfully import matplotlib.pyplot the installation of pyplot via pip3 was not necessary. What I was actually missing was the python3-tk package via apt. Now it works. Thank you.